How to search a list of repositories allowed in a Github Installation via the Github API?
I have a Github app which users can install on their account and give access to one or all of their repos.
Now I want to create an API where the user can search from the installed repos he has. I can create manual search as well but this would be slow and also in cases where users have given access to all repos, and they have a lot of repos, the API response time increases a lot.
This is the API I am using - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/installations?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repositories-accessible-to-the-app-installation
There is no search query params available here.
I looked at this as well - https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories
For this I should atleast know if the installation is a user or an organization. And based on that I can start the search. That's the only thing I can think of. As of now we only store the installation ID of the user in our DB.
Is there a simpler way I can search over the list of installed repos of the user?

this is less of a programming question and more of how to use github app tooling ... did you get an answer over at their forum  https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions

Sorry, I will repost the question there
